Deriving a three term recurrence relation from a DE using the Frobenius Method
I am trying to derive a three-term recurrence relation from the DE given by the equation below:
$$
\frac{d^2R(r)}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{dR(r)}{dr} + \left(2E - V(r) - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\right)R(r) = 0 \quad \text{Eq. 1}
$$
where:
$$
V(r) = -\frac{a}{r} + b r + r^2
$$
According to the author of this paperComment on Solution of Schrödinger equation for two different potentials using extended Nikiforov-Uvarov method and polynomial solutions of biconfluent Heun equation, J. Math. Phys. 59, 053501 (2018)
, one can obtain the three-term recurrence relation from Eq. 1 by using the Frobenius method with the following ansatz:
$$
R(r) = e^{-br/2 - r^2/2} r^l \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} r^j c_j
$$
I have tried doing the same. After replacing the ansatz into the DE and carrying out the algebra, I got this:
$$
e^{-br/2 - r^2/2} r^l \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left( A r^{j-1} c_j + B r^j c_j + C r^{j+1} c_j + 8 b r^{j+2} c_j + 8 r^{j+3} c_j \right) = 0 \quad \text{Eq. 2}
$$
where:
$$
A = 4j(j+2l+1)
$$
$$
B = -4(a + b(j+l+1))
$$
$$
C = b^2 - 8(j+l+E) - 12
$$
Now I have what looks like a 5 term recurrence relation! What did I do wrong? I would like to obtain the three-term recurrence relation in the following form from Eq. 2:
$$
c_{j+2} = A_j c_{j+1} + B_j c_j
$$
So how should I proceed now to get the recurrence relation result given in the paper? Could someone kindly advise? Thanking you in advance

If I use Mathematica to check Eq. 2, I don't get the last two terms and for $B$ I get $B=4(a -  b(j+l+1))$ instead. So that would be a three-term recurrence as expected. As such I suggest rechecking the algebra to get to Eq. 2.

@Semiclassical .Tqvm for your input. You  are right. i I rechecked the algebra by hand and ran it thru"Mathematica to confirm that there are only 3 terms. Your B term is the correct one, and C is actually  b^2-8(j+l-E) -12.
